# Form Align to Parent Form (left or Right)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to align/float other forms from parent form?

All I can found is MDI, for what I have understand, mdi will make the form visible inside the form, but what I wanted is to align other form from parent. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, you can create a monitor class and detect position change of each form and realign the second form when the first has moved

Comment: align means you want to show the 2 form in side the mdi like your image?

Comment: @T.S. how to do that?

Comment: Create a class which will know how to align the forms. It will also keep references of the forms. And it will receive events from forms - SizeChanged, LocationChanged, etc. It will determine which form has changed its parameters, and it will realighn the second form accordingly because it knows where they must be in relation to each other.

Answer (score 0):

From the original post:

---

Well, while in depth research I found the answer

```
Dim test As Integer = Form1.Width / 2
Dim sh As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2
Dim sw As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2

Dim nX As Integer = sw + (Form1.Width / 2) - 20
Dim nY As Integer = sh - (Form1.Height / 2)

Private Sub Form_Login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Me.Location = New Point(nX, nY)
  MsgBox(nX & ", " & nY)
End Sub
```